# Importing wikipedia-dump to SQL Incomplete

Tags: java, mysql, import, wikipedia, dump

I downloaded a Wikipedia dump from http://download.wikipedia.com/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2. Unzip it to `enwiki.xml` and run `php importDump.php < enwiki.xml`. It takes almost 2 days to finish. Somehow my local mediawiki has much less articles/pages/categories than the online wiki does.

`select count(*) from page;` only gives me `691716`. Another good example is page [United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) is missing on my local mediawiki.

I also tried to export a small xml from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export and use importDump.php to insert the xml into MySQL. The result looks fine. No page is missing.

**1. Am I downloading the wrong Wikipedia image, or something went wrong with the import process when the xml is huge?**

I've also tried both mwdumper.jar and the perl script according to [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313071/importing-wikipedia-dump-to-sql-base). Even though I alter the page table to have the page_counter column, all the articles are missing their content. Every page is saying:

> There is currently no text in this page.

**2. Is mwimport.perl and mwdumper.jar out of date?**

**3. Where could I get the complete Wikipedia dump and how could I import the dump into MySQL correctly?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the Wikipedia (and sibling projects) dumps in:

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html

In particular, if you are looking for the English Wikipedia:

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/

There you can find several dumps according to your needs. Particularly I use the "pages-articles" one, which contains the last revision of all the pages in all the namespaces:

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20190901/enwiki-20190901-pages-articles.xml.bz2

Take also into account that new dumps are generated about once a month.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I'm using pages-articles. But which import process do you use? It seems there isn't a working one. importDump.php seems to be working but the speed is super slow.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were already using the good dump, I have just discovered I can access the latest dump with the word `latest`. Thanks!

On the other hand, I don't import the dump, I just use it to parse it to find misspellings and other similiar stuff. But, as an estimation, I can tell you that only parsing the Spanish dump (uncompressed, in BZ2) in Python takes about 2 hours, and it is about a fifth the size of the English one.

Comment: No worries. FYI, I've already let the importDump.php running for almost a week and I'm still half way of it.

Comment: @zygimantus Yes, I did. I wrote my own code to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can share it? I have also slowness problems with importDump.php

Comment: @Top.Deck I'm also trying to import wiki xml dump. The speed by `importDump.php` is very slow. Could you please share your script?

Comment: @LEAnhDung I would love to share if I could, but that' company code. If you are just looking for Wikipedia corpus for ML then maybe https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikipedia could help.